# 2nd Function doesnt work until 1st function is completely executed in python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, project, python-multiprocessing

So basically, i have made a tkinter app that has a reminder utiliy in specific to generate notifications at the scheduled time. Everything works fine until I run the app module and another module having the notification generating function one at a time , but when I call the notification generating function intto the app module, my app doesnt work but the notification works. I want the app to run such that the notification generating function kind of runs in the background until the app module is open.

github link: https://github.com/click-boom/Trella

Looking into chatgpt i found terms like threading and multiprocessing, but i have no concept of that and still tried but didnt work.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please be aware that questions are intended as references to other people with similar problems; as such, all required information must be in the question itself. Please [edit] the question accordingly. Ideally, make sure to take the [tour] and have a look at the [ask] and [mre] help pages.

Answer (score -1):

Sure enough what you are looking for is multithreading.
Here is a simple example of how multithreading works (sorry for my lack of drawing skills).

This is how all monothread programs work. In most programming languages this is the default behaviour.

[image: monothreading example]

So in this example `Second Task` will have to wait for `First Task` to complete.
If you want several tasks to run concurrently, you can use multithreading.

[image: multithreading example]

This is how you could implement this in Python.

Monothreading:

```
from time import sleep

def firstTask():
    time = 10
    for i in range(time):
        sleep(1)
        print(f'I have been running for {i}s')

def secondTask():
    print('All I want to do is run once')

firstTask()
secondTask()
```

Here, `secondTask` will only run after `firstTask` is done (i.e after 10 seconds).

Multithreading:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def firstTask():
    time = 10
    for i in range(time):
        sleep(1)
        print(f'I have been running for {i}s')

def secondTask():
    print('All I want to do is run once')

first_thread = Thread(target=firstTask)
second_thread = Thread(target=secondTask)

first_thread.start()
second_thread.start()
```

I hope this will be a help to someone !

Comment: The question already mentions that they found (multi-)threading. Since it is specific to tkinter there is no need for threads, though – tkinter already provides cooperative concurrency.

Comment: i got the thing u just said. Let me clear up the scenario:
first thread= tkinter window which runs forever until i close the app
2nd thread= a function that generates notification by using sleep delay

so when i use thread here, the reminder function executes at the beginning causing the app window to not open until all the scheduled notifications have been run.

Therefore,I am looking for solution that allows me to run the notification function as background service allowing me to use the app whereas the notification is generated when the time deployed is met. Hope its clearer now.Help